# How to make your own Linux distro based on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, custom-distributions

I want to create an Linux distro based of Ubuntu 14.04 with a graphical user interface(GNOME) and cool terminal theme.

Comment: Basically this kind of questions Google is capable to answer. Check this http://www.wikihow.com/Build-Your-Own-Linux-Distro and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807259/how-easy-is-it-to-make-a-linux-distribution

Comment: Plus, there are a bunch Q/A's here about the exact same subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating Ubuntu distros is a common solution since Ubuntu itself became very popular as a desktop linux. Today, lots of projects are Ubuntu based, much beyond the official "flavors", Canonical's name for the official Ubuntu based distros. Linux Mint is an example of a Ubuntu based distro with a bigger level of customization.

To get the recommendations, go [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeDistroHowto). Those are stated as "unofficial", and very important info is there, such as reasons why one should do such a derivation, or not. Beyond that, it offers good practices to do the distro without loosing the benefits of an Ubuntu distro, and maybe more important, make your efforts more easy for the Ubuntu community to benefit from.

Answer (score 5):

- Well you can try with

### **LFS( Linux From Scratch)**

it's a *book
   describing the building of a Linux*..., google it.

- To make a distro based upon OpenSUSE, go to
  https://susestudio.com/

---

- To make a customized Ubuntu, you can start with
  ***www.instalinux.com/***
- Here's more about forking a distro from Ubuntu:

  > https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeDistroHowto

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help here is a link that might answer you :)

http://www.linuxvoice.com/build-your-own-linux-distro/

But am a starter from linux to Ubuntu is my prime os and I only use Ubuntu.
I don't think you can make your own linux distro with ubuntu. But there is version of Ubuntu like Lubuntu for light wight and Kubuntu and others.

But I hope this help :)

Comment: in fact there are lots of distros based on Ubuntu. ;) Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Linux Mint, Elementary OS and many others those are all based on Ubuntu.